# Sharedpreferences from inside a PagerAdapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi I'm trying to load data from the sharedpreferences inside a PagerAdapter and it wouldn't allow me is there any way I can do this or at least a way I can pass on this data from the activity creating the PagerAdapter to the PagerAdapter?

Hope I made the question clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PageAdapter constructor or method to pass in your app Context, so this will be something you will have to create manually.

It realy is as simple as making a setter and passing it your context.

```
public void setContext(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    mSharedPreference = mContext.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
}
```

then

```
pageAdapter.setContext(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Hi could you elaborate on that how do I read the context from the PagerAdapter also this code seems to be only partial thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to make that PageAdapter class as static
And make Context variable as static
Then call that setContext method through class name

```
PageAdapter.setContext(getApplicationContext());
```